# Add background with infinite width some elements in header

Tags: html, css

This is a live demo: http://baogiadientu.com/demo/fridgevan/
And the result that I want: http://baogiadientu.com/demo/fridgevan/images/demo.png

I want to add a background with an infinite width to two elements (`.top-bar` and `.nav`). I  have tried to do the same with `.bgwhite`'s background but a scroll bar is appearing, which is not what I want. Does anyone have any advice on how to achieve this without a scroll bar?

Here is my HTML structure:

```
<div class="container">

        <header class="clearfix">
            <div class="bgwhite"></div>
            <div class="logo">
                <img alt="logo" src="images/logo.png">
            </div> <!-- end .logo -->

            <div class="beside-logo">
                <div class="white-spce"></div>
                <div class="top-bar">

                </div> <!-- end .top-bar -->

                <div class="nav">

                </div> <!-- end .nav -->
            </div> <!-- end .beside-logo -->
        </header>

 </div> <!-- end .container -->
```

Comment: If by infinite you mean the full width of the browser then `width: 100%` should do the trick. If there will be horizontal scrolling you may have to use a javascript solution.

Comment: You can see this page, they don't use javascript. I've tried to do the same but the header is broken :)

Comment: Yes, but will users be scrolling horizontally?

Comment: No, users won't. It's not nice. As you can see on my live demo, I styled successfully .bgwhite to add a background with an infinite width but I can't do the same with right element :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure we would have to see the CSS in order to answer to this, but I suppose you have a .css file linked to that .html document, am I right?

In this case, just set the background image to **body** and mess around with the properties available for the **background** attribute.

```
body {
   background: url(images/yourbg.jpg) fixed center repeat-x;
}
```

And in case you mean to set a white background with a bit of transparency to it, so that the site's background is still coming up from back there, try this:

```
.nav {
   background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

Hope this helps, it's what I understood from the question.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I do the same this page http://fridgevan.kudoswebdesign.com/ but the result I archive is not the same. I don't understand that why they can do this :)